# How to break long text when print table to PDF

Tags: javascript, css, pdf, printing

i need to print table this table has 1 tr inside this tr i have 1 paragraph this paragraph contain very long text when print PDF Text is not fragmented 
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snHYG.jpg)
i am try with `page-break-inside: avoid;` but is not wirking

Comment: You can use print media queries, which is CSS that is only applied when printing a page. `@media print { #header, #footer, #nav { display: none !important; } }`

Comment: @elveti this is not my problem my problem is how to break text in paragraph when page in PDF is finish.